# Does the word 'Integral' relate in some way to the mathematical term?

Tags: meaning, etymology

The word *integral* in mathematics is a function that expresses the area under the graph of its derivative.

In English *integral* can mean necessary or essential.

Do either of these terms derive from the other? They do not seem to be related but perhaps there is a historical similarity?

Comment: A mathematical *integral* "integrates" the area contained within a curve into a single "complete" number.

Comment: That'd be a _definite integral_ which is of a portion of a function.

Comment: Your question has a definitive answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808285/why-are-integrals-called-integrals

Comment: Incorrect statement.  The word integral in mathematics is a function that expresses the area under the graph of it's derivative.    Under the graph (not derivative).   Derivative is opposite of integral.

Comment: @Paparazzi I'm not sure what you mean? yes they are opposites so the derivative of the integral of f(x) is f(x). When I said of _it's_ derivative I was referring to the derivative of the integral ie. the original function.

Comment: Odd way of expressing it to me.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral

Comment: @Aequitas: FYI _its_ derivative (not "it's")

Comment: Now that you know the answer to this question, you can explore related questions, like: why do calculus, the branch of mathematics, and calculus, that hardened plaque that dental hygienists scrape off your teeth, have the same name?

Comment: @EricLippert - That's easy -- they're both painful to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

The sense of the English word "integral" that relates to the mathematical usage is the adjectival meaning "whole".  From Wiktionary:

> Constituting a whole together with other parts or factors; not
>   omittable or removable

Something not omittable or removable can easily be seen to be necessary or essential.

The mathematical notions of "integers" and "integrals" relate to this meaning.  Another term for integers is "whole numbers", in the sense that they have no fractional part.  They don't have pieces--they are *whole*.

Integration in math is the process of summing up (in the limit) small pieces or slices of a shape (represented as the area under a function curve) into a *whole* area. In other words, from the pieces a whole is made.

The mathematical usage derives from the original meaning of "whole".